# How can I execute --log_dir ./logs_moco \

Tags: python, video, self-supervised-learning

This is the train part of the github page of VideoMoco

```
python train.py \  
  --log_dir ./logs_moco \  
  --ckp_dir ./checkpoints_moco \
  -a r2plusd_18 \
  --lr 0.04 \
  -fpc 32 \
  -b 256 \
  -j 128 \
  --epochs 200 \
  --schedule 120 160 \
  --dist-url 'tcp://localhost:10001' --multiprocessing-distributed --world-size 1 --rank 0 \
  DATA_DIR/kinetics-400
```

How can I execute --log_dir ./logs_moco \ and what is the meaning of that?

I already download kinetics 400 dataset and unzip the folder like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ee6qT.png)

Thank you.

..............................................

Comment: The backslash at the end of the line means the same as in Python: The command is continued in the next line, making everything just one long command with many arguments.